# Angular2 Aux route with parameters

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am building an Angular2 app, that has aux routing.
I was using this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/jZv8jj?p=preview
to help me with the setup, but I need to pass parameters to my aux link.
How do I do that? (note: this example uses the old hash routing, I am using he new html5, but it doesn't work in either method).

```
@Component({
    selector: 'basic-routing',
    template: `<a [router-link]="['/Home']">Home</a>
              <a [router-link]="['/ProductDetail']">Product Details</a>
              <router-outlet></router-outlet>
              <router-outlet name="chat"></router-outlet>
              <a href="./#/(chat)">Chat</a>`,
    directives: [ ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/',        component: HomeComponent, as: 'Home'},
    {path: '/product', component: ProductDetailComponent, as: 'ProductDetail'  },
    new AuxRoute({path: '/chat', component: ChatComponent, as: 'Chat'})
])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out... I am not sure this is the correct way to do it, but when I removed the paramenters from the aux path i.e.:

```
{aux:'/memory', name: 'Memory',   component: MemoryComponent}
```

instead of

```
{aux:'/memory/:id', name: 'Memory',   component: MemoryComponent}
```

it worked fine!